# C2DM register frequency

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

I'm testing the C2DM service. I implemented my code following this [GUIDE](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) and made a little php script for sending the messages and everything runs correctly.

Then I restarted the phone and (without opening the app) sent another message, and It was received too, so the how often have I to execute the **com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER** for always receive messages? Once per install or more frequently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the sequence of events that occurs when an Android application
>   running on a mobile device registers to receive messages:
>
> 1. The first time the application needs to use the messaging service, it fires off a registration Intent to a C2DM server. This registration
>      Intent (com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER) includes the sender
>      ID (that is, the account authorized to send messages to the
>      application, which is typically the email address of an account set up
>      by the application's developer), and the application ID.
> 2. If the registration is successful, the C2DM server broadcasts a REGISTRATION Intent which gives the application a registration ID. The
>      application should store this ID for later use. **Note that Google may
>      periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should design your
>      application with the understanding that the REGISTRATION Intent may be
>      called multiple times. Your application needs to be able to respond
>      accordingly.**
> 3. To complete the registration, the application sends the registration ID to the application server. The application server
>      typically stores the registration ID in a database.
>
> The registration ID lasts until the application explicitly unregisters
>   itself, or until Google refreshes the registration ID for your
>   application.

From [Google Android C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)